# Functional field - OpenErp - issue

Tags: python, function, orm, odoo

I added a `selection` type field, in `purchase.py` on it's class `purchase.order`, this field is called

`sel_cert`: `'sel_cert' : fields.selection([('si', 'Si'),('no','No')], 'Origen Certificado'),`

So if `si` is selected, there is a function i made in `product` which fills a new field in the `product_product` class when `purchase_order` is in `state 'done'`

Btw there is already a function which takes `product_qty` on state `done, draft` or whatever in `product`

I try to "call it" in my custom function with: `val = _get_product_available_func(('done'))` , so it returns `val` if `si` selected in the `sel_cert` field in `purchase.order`, but idk how to do it, this is my function, and under this function there is the traceback of the error i'm getting (don't care about indentation, it's not like this in my file):

```
def desc_cert(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, field_args, context=None):  
        obj = self.pool.get('purchase.order')  
        val = _get_product_available_func(('done'))  
        if obj.sel_cert == 'si':  
                return val
```

And the traceback:

```
Server Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 89, in send
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\service\web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 188, in execute_kw
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 131, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 197, in execute
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 185, in execute_cr
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\orm.py", line 3604, in read
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\orm.py", line 3724, in _read_flat
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\fields.py", line 1133, in get
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\openerp\addons\product\product.py", line 456, in desc_cert
NameError: global name '_get_product_available_func' is not defined
```

So `_get_product_available_func` is a function that comes before in the module `product.py`:

```
def _get_product_available_func(states, what):
    def _product_available(self, cr, uid, ids, name, arg, context=None):
        return {}.fromkeys(ids, 0.0)
    return _product_available

_product_qty_available = _get_product_available_func(('done',), ('in', 'out'))
_product_certificado_qty = _get_product_available_func(('done',), ('in', 'out'))
_product_virtual_available = _get_product_available_func(('confirmed','waiting','assigned','done'), ('in', 'out'))
_product_outgoing_qty = _get_product_available_func(('confirmed','waiting','assigned'), ('out',))
_product_incoming_qty = _get_product_available_func(('confirmed','waiting','assigned'), ('in',))
```

I need to return `product_qty_available` in `product`if this field `sel_cert` in `purchase_order` is `'si'`

But don't know how to call it, should i use `self.browse`? or maybe `product_available` instead?

Any ideas on this?

I hope i've explained myself

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that you want to write:

```
self._get_product_available_func
```

Comment: Yess, thank you very much =), but now i have another problem in ´obj = self.pool.get('purchase.order')´ it says ´purchase.order´ has no attribute ´sel_cert´ :(, do you figure out why? i mean ´sel_cert´ is a field (column) in the object ´purchase.order´

Comment: What i need is to retrieve from class 'purchase.order' the field 'sel_cert', any idea on how to do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe something like: 'purchase_obj.browse(cr, uid, sel_cert, context=context)' ?

Answer (score 0):

Use self.pool.get('class name in which function is written')._get_product_available_func